# Flash Player stopped working for protected content

Tags: 12.10, flash

I had Flash Player installed on two different computers running 12.10 along with the [HAL module](http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/flash-player-11-problems-playing.html) and everything was working just fine.

Until a couple days ago.

Now whenever I try to watch any sort of DRM protected videos, from any site, on any browser, on either computer, I get a message saying something to the effect that I need to update my Flash Player (the exact wording depends on the site I'm trying to view, of course).

I have checked to see if my [Flash Player is fully up to date](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/find-version-flash-player.html) and it is. I have also made sure run `apt-get update` and `apt-get dist-upgrade` on both machines and everything is up to date.

Despite the fact that it looks good, I tried uninstalling Flash Player and reinstalling it to no avail. I also tried reinstalling the HAL module and got the same result.

Any thoughts on what could be causing this and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you run `rm -rf .adobe/Flash_Player .macromedia/Flash_Player` in a terminal, and restarting the browser?

Comment: You should also re-install the browser plugin if the problems you are having are on the browser. Why use the proprietary version in the first place? GNASH works just fine.

Comment: @dobey Yup, I had done all that stuff when I installed HAL. Then again when I reinstalled Flash and HAL. No luck.